# SQL Developer Script Column Output Format

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently when i run a script in sql developer it looks like this:

**Script output:**

[image: Script Output]

However, I need it to look something like, as shown below, with the columns printed next to one another:

**Example:**

[image: Example]

Thanks, help is appreciated

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/T4J2I.png - This is another example

Comment: Assuming that you really want text output rather than the much more common grid output, `column "Recipe Name" format a30` will use 30 characters to display the `"Recipe Name"` column (longer names would wrap to the next line).

Answer (score 4):

You can specify different output formats using `SET sqlformat <format>`:

```
SET sqlformat ansiconsole;
```

Set that prior to your sql query and you should get a nicer format. If you look into the `sqlformat` option, there are others you can use, but `ansiconsole` is likely the one you want.

Then later, if you like, you can use `UNSET` on `sqlformat` to revert back to what you had previously.

```
UNSET sqlformat;
```

Comment: I have the same problem. This doesn't seem to take effect. No matter which `sqlformat` I choose I always get items on separate lines... I also tried changing `linesize`, but for some reason it doesn't get changed at all.